# WordPress Snippet to call Google Sheet Cell

Tags: php, json, wordpress, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've been using this PHP Snippet to display named ranges from a Google Sheet but every now and then the snippet will return an error...

The Code Snippet Plugin Log shows an error:
"023-03-23T16:51:35+00:00 Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

This is the snippet, and the error comes from the line "$cell_value = $json_body['values'][0][0];"

```
function sheet_value_shortcode($atts) {
$API = '[API KEY]';
$google_spreadsheet_ID = '[SPREADSHEET ID]';
$api_key = esc_attr( $API);

$location = $atts['location'];

$get_cell = new WP_Http();
$cell_url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEET-ID/values/$location?&key=API-KEY";
$cell_response = $get_cell -> get( $cell_url);

if ( is_wp_error( $cell_response ) ) {
    return 'An error occurred';
}

$json_body = json_decode($cell_response['body'],true);
$cell_value = $json_body['values'][0][0];
return $cell_value;

}
add_shortcode('get_sheet_value', 'sheet_value_shortcode');
```

I have tried limiting the call to once per day to limit the api but that did not solve the issue.